# bi publisher "Failed to Load XML" after trying to view data

Tags: bi-publisher

I am new to BI Publisher and I am receiving the error "Failed to Load XML" after trying to view the data generated by the following SQL code (runs successfully in SQL Developer):

```
SELECT oh.order_number, 
    ol.line_number, 
    ol.creation_date, 
    ol.ORDERED_ITEM, 
    ol.line_id as ITEM_KEY 
FROM ont.oe_order_lines_all ol, 
     ont.oe_order_headers_all oh 
WHERE ol.header_id = oh.header_id 
 and ol.attribute4 <> 'COPY' 
 and ol.line_id in 
 ( 
     SELECT to_number(item_key) 
     FROM APPS.WF_ITEM_ACTIVITY_STATUSES_V 
     WHERE activity_label = 'XXNM_BLOCK_ORDER_APPR_BLOCK' 
     and activity_status_code != 'COMPLETE' 
 ) 
 and ol.flow_status_code <> 'CLOSED' 
 and NVL(ol.cancelled_flag,'N') != 'Y' 
 ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

I am trying to create sample data to create a BI Publisher report. Our OBIEE version is 11.1.7.140715. Please provide assistance with what might be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to the query timing out in BI Publisher (which was not clearly stated in its error response or in the log file) but once we put an index on 'activity_status_code' view data completed without error.